# Unit of value calculated by using integral

Tags: calculus, integration, unit-of-measure

I have a really simple question that is driving me crazy!
I have a program which can log power and the result is a log file which contains two arrays, one with time values that show when a power value was logged and one with the corresponding power values. The unit of the x-values is seconds and the unit of the y-values is watt. Sample output:
\begin{equation*}
    x = [0, 1, 5, 100] \\
    y = [0, 0.2, 0.5, 1]
\end{equation*}
Now I would like to calculate the total amount of energy during these 100 seconds. As the x-values are different I can't just add the y-values together, but have to use a function like the composite trapezoidal rule. My simple question is this: what unit will the value from `trapezoidal(x, y)` have? My first thought was watt-during-100-seconds, but I also think that it can be watt times second.

Answer (score 1):

I have concluded that the answer to the question is watt-seconds. Just like when calculating an integral of velocity over time gives you `v*t = s`, caluclating an integral of power over seconds gives watt times seconds.